# python_speech_features package installation failure

Tags: python, anaconda

I am working on a `.py` module, which requires me to use the `python_speech_features` package. I wrote the following command in the Anaconda Prompt:

> conda install -c contango python_speech_features

But I am getting the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- python_speech_features
```

My system config:

> Python: 3.8.8
> Conda: 4.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is pure Python and no one is actively maintaining a Conda build, feel free to install from PyPI:

```bash
## activate environment
conda activate foo

## install dependencies
conda install pip numpy scipy

## install with pip
pip install python_speech_features
```